# C++ comparison with an assignment expression be the right hand side expression

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am currently working with a problem about data structure using C++.
I am going to check whether the nodes in a singly linked list are sorted in ascending order or not. Here comes some details of my code

Node.cpp

```
class Node
{
   public:
     double data;       
     Node* next;    
};
```

For the part that problem occurs,

```
double preValue = sLL.head->data;       
Node *curNode = sLL.head->next;     

    do
    {
        if (preValue > (preValue = curNode->data))  // Problem occur in this line   
            return false;
    }while (curNode = curNode->next);
```

As the order of evaluation of '>' operator is evaluating the left hand side expression and then the right hand side expression

AND

the assignment operator would return a reference of the lvalue.

Therefore, `preValue > (preValue = curNode->data)` should compares the last node and the current node and assign the data of the next node after the comparison is done. Therefore, I think my implementation should be valid.

However, the result of `if(preValue > (preValue = curNode->data))` is out of my expected, when comparing a `preValue` which is bigger than the new `preValue`, it keeps returning false.

I have tried to print out the return value of the if statement, it always return 0 whenever the left expression if greater or smaller than the right expression.
I cannot understand why this happen. Could anyone tell me what mistake did I made?

p.s. the program work fine with the following implementation

```
double preValue = list.head->data;      
Node *curNode = list.head->next;            

do
{
    if (preValue > curNode->data)       // Check ascending order
        return false;

    preValue = curNode->data;

}while (curNode = curNode->next);
```

Comment: .. so why don't you just use the second implementation? It's easier to read anyway.

Comment: yes, I used that implementation but I still want to know why the original implementation doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is Undefined Behavior:

```
if (preValue > (preValue = curNode->data))  // Problem occur in this line
```

because you're assigning to a variable (`preValue`) and reading from that same variable, and *the read is not used to determine the value written*.

From C++03 §5/4 `[expr]`:

> [...] Between the previous
>   and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation
>   of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.
>   The requirements of this paragraph shall be met for each allowable ordering of the subexpressions of a full
>   expression; otherwise the behavior is undefined.

A *sequence* point occurs after full expressions (i.e. semicolon-terminated expressions or statements), as well as after the first operands of the `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and `,` operators.  All other operators (including the `>` operator) do *not* have sequence points between the evaluations of their arguments.  Sequence points also occur in a few other places not relevant to this question.

The fix, as you said, is to just break it apart so that the assignment happens in a separate statement from the comparison.

When I compile this code with GCC with the `-Wall` compiler flag, I get this warning:

```
warning: operation on ‘preValue’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
```

I highly recommend you always compile with `-Wall` and `-Werror` so that these errors get flagged immediately by the compiler and you can correct them.

Comment: Thanks for your reference and advice. This help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
if (preValue > (preValue = curNode->data))
```

is an undefined behaviour. See the concepts of [sequence points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45c7a5d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). An expression can modify its objects only once between two sequence points and '>' is not a sequence point.